# What should the bounds of integration be and why?

Tags: probability, integration, density-function

I'm stuck on a question because I don't quite understand the concept behind it. The question says:

> "Let's find the proportion of values that lie within one standard deviation of the mean. What should the bounds of integration be and why?"

I think the bounds would be from $0$ to $1$ because we're looking for one standard deviation and (I'm assuming) the mean$=0$. Can someone explain whether this is right or wrong?

Comment: Can you show the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably you are considering a normal distribution with mean $0$ and standard deviation $1$, facts you should have supplied with the question.  The numbers within $1$ of zero are the range $(-1,1)$, not $(0,1)$.